# Sum aggregation in ELK

Tags: elk

I have a one value paymentAmount in the string field called @message. I want to fetch the data from @message and do the sum aggregation for that value called paymentAmount in elk devtool
In @message there is log message in the log i want to fetch the paymentamount that is look like this \”paymentAmount\” :1089.33,

Can you help to get that code